# MySQL DATE_ADD not returning correct date

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(`vj`.`departure`, INTERVAL sum(`run_time`) SECOND) AS arrivalTime 
  FROM myTable

vj.departure = 09:15:00  
sum(run_time) = 2070
```

The result I thought I would get from the query based on the values above would be: `09:49:30`. Instead, I am seeing: `10:19:30.000000`.

If I run the query like this: `DATE_ADD(vj.departure, INTERVAL 2070 SECOND) AS arrivalTime` the query then works fine and returns the correct result: `09:49:30`. This is not my goal however, I need to pass in the `sum(run_time)` value.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: What if you will try to use variable?

Comment: Please, [post your table structure and sample data here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I think your sum(run_time) is not equal to 2070. I tried with sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c185/2/0 and it's OK

Comment: @JoeTaras he already mentioned, that when he is using query like yours he gets correct results. But we cannot excude, that there is more to current query, like the `WHERE` conditions, which limiting the result of the `sum`

Comment: @Alexander: You're right. the secret of solution is in the sum(run_time), but our OP must post a example data (as you adviced him)

Comment: @JoeTaras Her? Excuse me? xD

Comment: I'll post the schema in a few moments - I have been distracted with something work-related, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose, that you get the wrong value for `vj.departure`.

Given a table like this:

```
departure | runtime
----------+---------
06:06:06  | 1000
09:15:00  | 1070
```

When you use the `SUM()` function, all rows are collapsed. Since you didn't specify an aggregate function in your query for `departure` column and also don't have it in a `GROUP BY` clause, a random row of all rows is chosen to be displayed. So I'd guess, that in the example above the row with the value `06:06:06` is chosen, therefore you get a wrong result.

Comment: Any guesses on day light time differences too?

Comment: You mean time zones? Why should it have anything to do with that?

Comment: Just an assumption as the time difference shown is exact 30 minutes. And also the `departure` field seems to be from a different table than `runtime` field.